# Is this operation with limits possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I've seen this aproximation quoted many times when it comes to holomorphic functions:

$f(z)\approx f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$ around $z_0$

I would like to prove it formally, which seems straightforward, but with limits it's easy to overlook details, so here goes:

If $f$ is holomorphic then the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_o)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0)$ exists. Both $h(z)=f(z)-f(z_o)$ and $g(z)=z-z_0$ are continuous in all $\mathbb{C}$.

$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_o)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0) \Longrightarrow \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}z-z_0 \cdot \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_o)}{z-z_0}= \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}z-z_0 \cdot f'(z_0) \Longrightarrow \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{(z-z_0)(f(z)-f(z_o))}{z-z_0}= \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}z-z_0 \cdot f'(z_0) \Longrightarrow \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)-f(z_o)=\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}z-z_0 \cdot f'(z_0) \Longrightarrow \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} z-z_0$

Which I think is what I was looking for.

Comment: $$\lim_{z\to z_0} z-z_0 = 0$$ That is $$\lim_{z\to z_0} z-z_0 \cdot\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}= 0$$

Comment: Multiplying by zero both sides of an equation does not lead very far.

Comment: Well, you have to prove, that $f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)f'(z_0)+O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct proof. $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}z-z_0=0$$ and so your equalities fall apart since you multiplied both sides by $0$.

I would recommend proving this using Cauchy's Theorem, which says that every holomorphic function is analytic (i.e. has a power series that it converges to). This power series is given by Taylor Polynomials, and the first two terms of it are $f(z)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$, which is why the equality is true. You can apply the Lagrange error formula for power series to bound the error of the approximation to finish the proof.